# Java app not closing connections

Tags: java

I'm working on a reasonably large Java application that does HTTP calls from different classes to get data. It runs for some time and at the end of the run waits for some hours until it starts the run again. (Why it's done this way is beyond the point here and out of my control unfortunately.)

I have an issue because in between runs some HTTP connections remain open (I checked with `netstat -p |grep <pid>`). I've gone through the code to see where we should be closing connections but aren't and wasn't able to find anything. Most request are of the type `Unmarshaller.unmarshal(url)`.

So my question is this: Is there a way where, at the end of the run, I check for connections on a particular port that this application maintains and close them?

Comment: Can you show the code that opens a connection, reads and then closes?

Comment: Sure, here's an example: `SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse) unmarshaller.unmarshal(url);`

Comment: And this closes automatically? Uh. You can always first read the contents and _then_ unmarshal; this way the two processes are uncorrelated and it becomes easier to spot the problems.

Comment: Yes that sounds reasonable, I'll try

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is the HTTP spec itself.  I suspect that the connection isn't closed immediately because the spec doesn't guarantee the delivery time of each and every packet.

It could be a web server configuation to tell it how long to keep connections alive.  I'd investigate that.  Maybe you can use a tool like Fiddler or even Chrome developer tools to look at the HTTP headers and see what the keep alive header is set to:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the web server. And I'm not sure this is the issue - I've noticed connections a few hours after the request is made.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Well that's arguable and probably doesn't justify downvoting the person for trying to help.

Comment: tbsalling, I get sick and tired of noobs like you making useless comments about the answers of others without offering anything of value yourself.  Don't worry about the category for my answers; let's see what wisdom you can summon.  Post what you have that's better, please.  Let's see if you can build up that paltry rep of yours.

Comment: Well I sincerely apologize if I offended 161k member by expressing an opinion, though I still fail to see the answer in the answer. But no need for me to comment in the same tone. I have annulled the downvote.

Comment: Like I said, post your better answer so I can see what true wisdom looks like.